# How to take the value of select form when :selected property is not added to the options, in jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to do something with my selection form value. If yes is selected, the button text become "Yes" if no is selected, button text is "No"

Here is my code,

```js
var deal = jQuery("#deal").val();
var no = "No";
var yes = "Yes";
if (deal == no) {
    // do something
}
if (deal == yes) {
   // do some other thing
}
```

```html
<label>Value</label>
<select id="deal">
  <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
  <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
</label>
<button class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write the code in change event:

```
$("#deal").change(function(){
   $(".output").text($(this).find('option:selected').text());
}).change(); //to set the value to button after binding event
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ohjbsx2h/)**

**Update : Modified as per OPs requirement:**

```
$("#deal").change(function(){
 if($(this).find('option:selected').text() == "Yes"){
  alert('yes');
  }else{
   alert('no');
  }
}).change();
```

Comment: Hi, your answer works fine. Please take a look at my edited question. I want to do different things based on the selection value

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for that. If you change your answer, I may put a green signal on that....

Comment: One thing, onloading the page, Yes is selected by default, but alert is not showing. How to do that ?

Comment: you need to follow the same approach as i suggested in first answer. trigger after attaching the event `.change()`.